# Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable - jwt token error

Tags: python

i am running into this error when i am trying to run a get request for my login page in postman:

code is as follows:

```
def jwt_required(func):
@wraps(func)
def jwt_required_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    token = request.args.get('token')
    if not token: 
        return jsonify( { 'message' : 'Token is missing'} ), 401
    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config, ['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms = "HS256")
    except:
        return jsonify( { 'message' : 'Token is invalid'} ), 401
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
return jwt_required_wrapper
```